# matplotlib: how to position text precisely?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating a bunch of little images to overlay on a video clip, using Matplotlib (I'm adding a sort of speedometer plus some other info).

However, I have been unable to position exactly a number vertically (so that the decimal dot is always exactly at the same place). The variation is very subtle, and it is only in the video that it looks odd because the number "dances" up and down by 1 pixel.

I've tried a number of things, using `annotate`:

- change the `va` (`'top'`, `'bottom'`, `'baseline'`, etc.);
- change the `xycoords` system (`'figure points'`, `'figure pixels'`, `'data'`);
- change the `textcoords` system (`'offset points'`, `'offset pixels'`);
- figure `constrained_layout` or not;
- various `dpi` and size values.

But to no avail: depending on whether some digits are displayed, the vertical position changes slightly.

The real plot is complex, but below is a minimal example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image

def no_frame(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(False)
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    
def test(texts, width=1.5, height=0.5, dpi=72):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height))
    no_frame(ax)
    for i, text in enumerate(texts):
        ax.annotate(text,
                    (i*40, 5), xycoords='figure points',
                    xytext=(0, 0), textcoords='offset points',
                    ha='left', va='baseline', fontsize=36)
    
    # save as PIL Image
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, dpi=dpi, format='png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
    plt.close(fig)
    buf.seek(0)
    image = Image.open(buf)
    return image
```

Then, here is a pathological case and how to display the unexpected vertical variation (the dot of both texts `'.1'` and `'.15'` should be at the same height, but the digit `5` wreaks havoc):

```py
im = test(('.1', '.15'), dpi=72)
a = np.asarray(im).copy()

# make a red line at the bottom of the text
ypix = np.where(a.min(axis=1)[:, 0] == 0)[0].max()
a[ypix, :] = (255, 0, 0, 255)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 2))
no_frame(ax)
ax.imshow(a)
```

[image]

Is there a way to force the text to be exactly at the same vertical position? (I would have expected the `va='baseline'` to achieve that, but clearly that's not the case).